# How to pass multiple variables as input in shell script in non-interactive way

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I am trying to make this interactive script take inputs in a non-interactive way by declaring $username and $password variables in bash env and pass them as inputs to the script. By running ./input.sh <<< "$username"

```
#!bin/bash
read username
read password
echo "The Current User Name is $username"
echo " The  Password is $password"
```

is there a way to pass both the variables as input? Because with what I have tried it only takes one input this way.

Comment: But if ``$username`` and ``$password`` are in bash env, then you can access them from your script, can't you? That's the whole point of env variables.

Comment: @chrslg yes they can be accessed , but I want to know If what i am trying to do can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "The Current User Name is $1"
echo "The Password is $2"
```

$1 represents the first given argument and $2 the second.

```
[user@vm ~]$ input.sh "user" "password"
```

Inside the quotation marks ("") put the argument you want to pass.

For more professional/robust solution check this out: [Redhat: Bash Script Options/Arguments](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/arguments-options-bash-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

So, staying as close as possible as your initial try (but I doubt that is the best solution for any real problem), what you are asking is "how I can pass 2 lines with here-string".

A possible answer would be

```bash
./input.sh <<< "$username"$'\n'"$password"
```

**here-strings** are the construct you are using when using `<<<`. When you type `./input.sh <<< astring` it is, sort-of, the same as if you were typing `echo astring | ./input.sh`: it use the string as standard input of `./input.sh`. Since your `read`s read lines, you need 2 lines as standard input to achieve what you want. You could have done this that way: `(echo "$username" ; echo "$password") | ./input.sh`. Or anyway that produces 2 lines, one with `$username` one with `$password` and redirecting those 2 lines as standard input of `./input.sh`

But with here-string, you can't just split in lines... Unless you introduce explicitly a carriage return (`\n` in c notation) in your input string. Which I do here using `$'...'` notations, that allows c escaping.

Edit. For fun, I include here the other solutions I wrote in comments, since you are not specially requiring here-strings.

```bash
(echo "$username" ; echo "$password") | ./input.sh
{echo "$username" ; echo "$password" ; } | ./input.sh
printf "%s\n" "$username" "$password" | ./input.sh
./input.sh < <(echo "$username" "$password")
./input.sh < <(printf "%s\n" "$username" "$password")
```

Plus of course solutions that changes `./input.sh`

```bash
#!bin/bash
username="$1"
password="$2"
echo "The Current User Name is $username"
echo " The  Password is $password"
```

called with `./input "$username" "$password"`

Or

```bash
#!bin/bash
echo "The Current User Name is $username"
echo " The  Password is $password"
```

called with `username="$username" password="$password" ./input.sh`

Comment: not specifically here-string i just used them as an example , i tried echoing the two variables as input echo"$username" "$password " | ./input.sh I was doing it wrong ! Thanks for the explanation. Your solutions worked !! But are there any other ways to do it aswell?

Comment: Well, you could have passed username and password as an argument. ``./input.sh "$username" "$password"`` and then drop the reads in input.sh and username and password are ``$1`` and ``$2``.

Comment: You could have passed them as env value (even just locally), like this: ``username="$username" password="$password" ./input.sh``. Which creates an environment just for this call of input.sh. And then, again, in input.sh, drop the reads, and the variables are called ``$username`` and ``$password``

Comment: Or, if needed not to change at all ``input.sh``, that is to keep the read, and then, to find way to pass 2 lines to ``input.sh``, well, we covered the not too covoluted way, I would say: ``(echo name ; echo pass) | ./input.sh``, or ``./input.sh <<< name$'\n'pass``. One might add ``printf "%s\n" "$username" "$password" | ./input.sh``. That is just a variation around the pairs of echo that doesn't require a subshell. In bash, you can also compound a pair of echo without subshell (the ``(...)`` starts a subshell), with ``{echo "$username" ; echo "$password" ; } | ./input.sh``.

Comment: Beware, the second comma is compulsory

Comment: A more convoluted version would be ``./input.sh < <(echo "$username" ; echo "$password")``. With a space between the 2 ``<`` and no space between the ``<`` and the ``(``. It means ``./input.sh`` with standard input being the "file" ``<(echo "$username" "$password")``. Knowing that in bash, ``<(whatever)`` is a "file" (not a real one. More a pipe) whose content is the result of of ``whatever`` command.